# Non-gaming video card and KVM

Tags: video, kvm

I'm looking for a non-gaming video card with two HDMI or displayport outputs and a KVM that has inputs to connect 2 computers via USB.

Comment: There is a ton of info here that isn't necessary. You need a non-gaming video card with two outputs (HDMI | VGA | DVI | DP) and a KVM that has Z number of inputs and outputs in (USB | HDMI | DVI). Can you edit your question for clarity please?